# Elasticsearch Python not saving index anymore after a number of iterations

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch with a python script to store some relationships between IDs that I read from a CSV file. I'm using the Colab environment to run this.

The problem is: after running through some iterations, the script stucks in the last line "es.index", used to save or update a document. More specifically, it gets stuck with 700 doc count (don't know exactly whether the problem is related to this). Here, the algorithm keeps "processing" this line, until connection timeout.

Here is the code I use:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

ES_NODES = "http://localhost:9200"
es = Elasticsearch(hosts = [ES_NODES])

path = '/content/test.csv'

#create the index
if not es.indices.exists('relacoes_produtos'):
    print('Criando índice')
    res = es.indices.create(index='relacoes_produtos')
    print("Response from server: {}".format(res))

with open(path, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        produtos = line.strip().replace(' ','')
        produtos.rstrip('\x00')
        produtos = produtos.split(',')
        print(produtos)
        produtos = list(dict.fromkeys(produtos))

        for id in produtos:
            if es.exists(index="relacoes_produtos", id=str(id)):
                res = es.get(index="relacoes_produtos", id=str(id))
                doc_prod = res['_source']
                doc_prod['ocorrencias'] += 1

                for produto in produtos:
                    if id != produto:
                        if produto in doc_prod['relacoes']:
                            doc_prod['relacoes'][produto] += 1
                        else:
                            doc_prod['relacoes'][produto] = 1
            else: 
                doc_prod = {
                    'id':str(id),
                    'ocorrencias':1,
                    'relacoes':{}
                }

                for produto in produtos:
                    if id != produto:
                        if produto in doc_prod['relacoes']:
                            doc_prod['relacoes'][produto] += 1
                        else:
                            doc_prod['relacoes'][produto] = 1
            
            print(id)
            res = es.index(index="relacoes_produtos", id=str(id), body=doc_prod, request_timeout=10000000)
```

Someone knows how to solve it?

Comment: can you add some debugging here to see what the Elasticsearch response is, and/or check Elasticsearch logs

Comment: Hi, Mark! Thanks for your answer! could you please tell me what you exactly would want to see in this response? Don't know exactly what to run here (don't know much about elasticsearch)

Comment: your only debugging is currently the "if index doesn't exist", you don't do anything when you are indexing to catch potential errors. so maybe something is going wrong with a document and your code isn't catching or can't cope with it

Comment: Do not use `id`, it's a python core function